# execute AsyncTask in the method service OnDestroy()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this problem, i need to run a AsyncTask when a service that it is pooling data in the application is destroyed,but i have the following issue, i can put the code without an AsyncTask because it can't be doing on the main thread, and when i'm doing the call of execute in the method onDestroy the task never is executed.
this is the code of the onDestroy method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    new StartPushNotification().execute();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And this is the code of the task that i'm trying to execute:

```
private class StartPushNotification extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            String deviceId = instanceID.getId();
            AppManager manager = AppManager.getManager(getApplication());
            Identity identity = manager.RetrieveSharedIdentityObject();
            Boolean res = manager.SaveRegistration(String.valueOf(identity.getIdentityAccountNumber()), identity.getIdentityUser(), identity.getIdentityPassword(), "True", deviceId, "ooo");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note: I tried to debug the method and the OnDestroy method it is execute, but the AsyncTask not.
Any help with that please?

Comment: I've had a similar problem while trying to save data to SharedPreference in Service onDestroy(). From my experience, you can't rely on code to be executed in onDestroy().

Comment: Are you sure it isn't starting and not starting then throwing an exception? Also, you really don't need an `AsyncTask` since you aren't doing anything on the UI thread. You could simply run a new Thread.

Comment: yeah, a simple one-off thread would do

Comment: Thank you, sorry but i don't get what you are saying me in that comment about the "new Thread"...

Comment: And i'm sure that the problem is not an exception because i have a breakpoint into the doInBackground and never the debugger fired the breakpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, instead of using `AsyncTask`, as suggested by codeMagic.

```
private class MyThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            String deviceId = instanceID.getId();
            AppManager manager = AppManager.getManager(getApplication());
            Identity identity = manager.RetrieveSharedIdentityObject();
            Boolean res = manager.SaveRegistration(String.valueOf(identity.getIdentityAccountNumber()), identity.getIdentityUser(), identity.getIdentityPassword(), "True", deviceId, "ooo");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    new Thread(new MyThread()).start();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Perfect DavidH, it is working in this way, thank you so much!!! Just one thing that i have to change it is: new Thread(new MyThread()).run();

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera Don't call run() on the Thread. Calling run() on the thread is just like calling a normal method...meaning it will run in the same thread as the Service.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead of your AsyncTask, since you don't need UI updates anyway.

```
    @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
                    String deviceId = instanceID.getId();
                    AppManager manager = AppManager.getManager(getApplication());
                    Identity identity = manager.RetrieveSharedIdentityObject();
                    Boolean res = manager.SaveRegistration(String.valueOf(identity.getIdentityAccountNumber()), identity.getIdentityUser(), identity.getIdentityPassword(), "True", deviceId, "ooo");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: Additionally, check if `getApplicationContext()`, `getApplication()` aren't `null.`

Comment: oops my answer == yours. Bad timing

Comment: Yeah, I was typing. It happens.